# Hibernate - How to map a one-to-many relationship with an extra column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relationship

I am currently learning JPA and Hibernate and I'm working on a project in which my object model looks like this:

[image: uml-diagram]

ie. A one-to-many relationship with an additional field.

Q: What is the correct way to map this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You have many possibilities for this. For me, in relation one to many, you should make the data of the relation inside the (many) side of the relation. In your case, inside the Card.

```
@Entity
class Section {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "section")
  private List<Card> cards;

  public Section() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

@Entity
class Card {
  private int position;
}
```

This is an example you should adapt it with your own data.

Comment: But the position only depends on the section where the card is (you can move a card from one section to another and change the position). That is why at first I did not think to simply add the position to the class Card.